# JPA @SecondaryTable foreign key violation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, mapping

I want to map two entities in a `one to many` fashion.

```
A->[B, B]
```

I want to add to the  `join table` more fields. `Pojos` looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A", schema = "examples")
@SecondaryTable(name = "A_B", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
public class A
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Basic
    private String name;

    @Basic
    private Integer field1;

    @Column(table = "A_B", name = "field2")
    private Integer field2;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "b_id")})
    private List<B> datastores;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "B", schema = "examples")
@SecondaryTable(name = "A_B", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
public class B
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;


    @Basic
    private String field1;

    @Basic
    private int field2;

    @Column(table = "A_B", name = "field3")
    private int field3;
}
```

Thing is that in order to add I had to remove the `foreign key` on `A_B` table. How do I solve the mapping to allow the `foreign keys` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am missing something, but I don't see why both Entity A and Entity B are mapping to table "A_B".  By adding it to Entity A as a secondary table, you are stating that every time an insert to Table a occurs, an insert to table A_B must also occur - creating a strict 1:1 relation between rows in the two tables.  Except that you do the same thing to entity B, so you will end up with rows in A_B with A_id=somevalue, and B_id= null and others with a_id=null while b_id=somevalue.  Table "A_B" looks like a relation table, so this probably isn't what you want.

If A_B is a relationtable you should map it using a ManyToMany as you have for the "A_B" table.  If there are extra fields that need to be populated, create a AB Entity, and create a OneToMany from A->AB and B->AB, and ManyToOne from AB->A and AB->B.